# How to get automatic SCHEMA UPDATE on an existing DB with JPA/Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0, database-schema

I am trying to update my existing DB schema automatically with JPA-based app (I am using Hibernate as a Persistence provider). What I did is that I have positioned my **hbm2dll** param to "update" like this in the persistence.xml :

```
 <properties>
     <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
     <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
     ...
 </properties>
```

But it seems that Hibernate can not handle the schema generation.

Can you please tell me how I can automatically update my running DB schema with JPA/Hibernate if any other option than the **hbm2dll** is available?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/438146/hibernate-question-hbm2ddl-auto-possible-values-and-what-they-do/1689769#1689769

Answer (score 1):

Don't do that in production. Write your schema manually and then maintain it using [Liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/) or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Your setting is correct  ,but database must be created manually.Hibernate will create tables.And you can also set value to  create,update .

Comment: Hi guyz,
thanks a lot for your responses. Actually, after diving into the logs, I saw that the user I have configured in the app to connect to the DB didn't have the privileges to ALTER TABLES : so my sysadmin changed that and now it works ;-)